# QProcess.write to python script failed

Tags: python, qprocess

I use Qt4 QProcess to run one python3.4 script in new QThread. I want to input something to the script while it is still running. But every time I write, the program has unexpectedly finished, and the python script is still running background. Don't know why
start part:

```
process = new QProcess;
QObject::connect(process,SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()),this,SLOT(outlogs()));
process->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
process->start("python3 -i -u /home/circleone/Desktop/test.py",QProcess::Unbuffered | QProcess::ReadWrite);
if (!process->waitForStarted())
    exit(1);
```

write part:

```
QByteArray a=str.toAscii();
int b=strlen(a);
process->write(a,b);          //it failed in this line
process->closeWriteChannel();
process->waitForBytesWritten();
process->waitForReadyRead();
```

read output part:

```
QString resultstr = process->readAllStandardOutput();
emit returnResult(resultstr);
```

python script:

```
import threading
import time
import sys
import os

class Test(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        global strtest
    while True:
        test = input()
        print(test)
        strtest=test
        time.sleep(0.5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global strtest
    strtest=''
    thread = Test()
    thread.start()
    while True:
        if(strtest == 'exit'):
            print('quit')
            os.abort()
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Please post the output and errors if there are any...

Comment: there really have nothing output
there are the Application Output:
Starting /home/circleone/build-Test-Desktop-Debug/Test...
process start 
The program has unexpectedly finished.
/home/circleone/build-Test-Desktop-Debug/Test crashed